# Making a section of a page readonly in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, readonly, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates

I would like to make a section of a page read only while other sections can be editable. Is this possible in mediawiki? I know I can add the **NOEDITSECTION** tag, and it removes the edit links in the section, but I still can edit it in the main edit page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not explicitly, no.  But here's what you could do instead:

Put your read only section on a new page and *protect* it. [Transclude](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion) the contents of that protected page onto the primary page.  A user would still have the opportunity edit the primary page and entirely remove the section, but they cannot edit the contents of that section.

If your protected page is named MyProtectedPage, then you'd put `{{:MyProtectedPage}}` on the primary page to transclude it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mediawiki extension called ProtectSection which was designed to do exactly what you're requesting.  However, it has not been maintained for years.  I've been unable to get it working on the latest version of MediaWiki, but if you're running an older version, perhaps it will work for you.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ProtectSection